# submit a form twice to different scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

For some reason I need to transmit a form to 2 different scripts at the same time.
Any idea how i can do that? Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery("#form1").validate({
    debug: true,
    submitHandler: function() {
        var dataString = jQuery("#order_form form").serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkout.php",
            data: dataString,
            //dataType: text,
            success: function(msg) {
                jQuery('#order').animate({ left: '400px'}, 4000, 'linear').fadeOut(2500);
                jQuery('#form1').animate({ left: '400px'}, 0, 'linear').fadeOut(0);
                //jQuery('#left').css('left', '400px');
                jQuery('#order_form').html("<div style='margin-top:117px; text-align:center;' id='message'></div>");
                jQuery('#message').html("<p class='text'>Thank you</p>")
                    .append("<p class='text' style='margin-bottom:15px;'></p>")
                    .fadeIn(500, function() {
                        jQuery('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='form/ok.png'  >");
                });
            },
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Make another AJAX request to the second URL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by adding another ajax code for second page like,

```
submitHandler: function() {
   $.ajax();// first
   $.ajax();// second
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ver very much for your quick anser.
In this way, right behind the first one (sorry, I'm a neewbie)?

```
 **jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkout.php",
        data: dataString,
        //dataType: text,
        success: function(msg) {**
            jQuery('#order').animate({ left: '400px'}, 4000, 'linear').fadeOut(2500);
            jQuery('#form1').animate({ left: '400px'}, 0, 'linear').fadeOut(0);
            //jQuery('#left').css('left', '400px');
            jQuery('#order_form').html("<div style='margin-top:117px; text-align:center;' id='message'></div>");
            jQuery('#message').html("<p class='text'>Thank you</p>")
                .append("<p class='text' style='margin-bottom:15px;'></p>")
                .fadeIn(500, function() {
                    jQuery('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='form/ok.png'  >");
            });
        },



**jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkout2.php",
        data: dataString,
        //dataType: text,

            });
        },
```